# Normalize a vector with pre-defined mean

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to normalize a vector such that the mean of the normalized vector would be a certain pre-defined value. For instance, I want the mean to be 0.1 in the following example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

array = np.arange(1,11)
array_norm = normalize(array[:,np.newaxis], axis=0).ravel()
```

Of course, `np.mean(array_norm)` is 0.28 and not 0.1. Is there a way to this in Python?

Comment: "Normalize" has two meanings; one is to adjust a physical vector's length to 1.0; the other is aimed at a non-physical vector (simple array), and results in a feature whose values have a particular range (e.g. [0, 1] ) or a particular mean & standard deviation.  Which did you want?

Comment: If you want the latter, then there are two straightforward ways to do it.  (1) Look through the scientific support packages, such as `math` and `scikit`, for a packaged function.  (2) Look up the algorithm for typical normalization (i.e. mean 0, s.d. 1.0), and alter the mean parameter to your desired value.

Comment: @Prune I meant the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just multiply each element by `mean_you_want / current_mean`. If you multiply each element by a scalar, the mean will also be multiplied by that scalar. In your case, that would be `0.1/np.mean(array_norm)`

```
array_norm *= 0.1/np.mean(array_norm)
```

This should do the trick.